# SetOnCompletionListener is called after some delay

Tags: android, stream, android-videoview, rtsp

I am using a VideoView widget of Android to play a RTSP stream. I have set SetOnPreparedListener and SetOnCompletionListener no VideoView. Now when I close my RTSP server, my VideoView SetOnCompletionListener is getting called, but it is called after an delay of 20-25 seconds after I close the server. The video playing on the client is stopped just after closing the server but SetOnCompletionListener is called after delay.

Is this expected? If the VideoView widget checks for some time to see if the stream is closed or not, how much time is that and can I change that time?

Comment: on real device
Nexus 4,
Samsung Galaxy Tab 4